# Rails :has_many :through sort order issue in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rspec-rails

I am having some weird behavior in a Rails model and I'm not quite sure why.  Thanks to anyone who can point me as to what I'm missing or not understanding.

**The Problem**

I have a model Car with a has_many :through relationship on Part through CarsPart.  I expect accessing a car's parts to be in alphabetical order.  I created the model specs and the controller specs.  In the controller, the parts are ordered in alphabetical order as called out in the has_many relationship.  In the controller spec, they are in order.  In the model spec, they are not.    I don't think it's tied to the testing framework because i've debugged the running server and see the same behavior.

**The Code**

*Car*

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cars_parts
  has_many :parts, -> { order('name asc') }, through: :cars_parts, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars_parts, :allow_destroy => true

  validates :make, :model, presence: true

  validate :validate_cars_parts

  def validate_cars_parts
    errors.add(:parts, "wrong number") if self.cars_parts.size < 1

    self.cars_parts.each do |car_part|
      part = Part.find(car_part.part_id)
      errors.add(:parts, "doesn't exist") if part == nil
    end
  end
end
```

*Part*

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :cars_part
  has_many :cars, through: :cars_parts

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

*CarsPart*

```
class CarsPart < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :part

end
```

*Cars Controller Spec*  **Passes**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CarsController, type: :controller do
  render_views

  context 'property features' do

    describe "GET #show/id returns ordered parts" do

      before :each do
        @p4 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'BPart2')
        @p3 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'APart2')

        @p6 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'BPart3')
        @p5 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'APart3')

        @p2 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'BPart1')
        @p1 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'APart1')
      end

      it 'returns parts in alphabetical order' do
        car = FactoryGirl.create(:car, make: 'Nissan', model: 'Murano', parts: [@p4, @p3, @p6, @p5, @p2, @p1])

        get :show, id: car.id, format: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
        expect(response).to render_template(:show)

        response_json = JSON.parse(response.body)

        response_json['parts'].each do |part|
          puts part['id']
        end

        expect(response_json['parts'].size).to eq(6)
        expect(response_json['parts'][0]['id']).to eq(@p1.id)
        expect(response_json['parts'][1]['id']).to eq(@p3.id)
        expect(response_json['parts'][2]['id']).to eq(@p5.id)
        expect(response_json['parts'][3]['id']).to eq(@p2.id)
        expect(response_json['parts'][4]['id']).to eq(@p4.id)
        expect(response_json['parts'][5]['id']).to eq(@p6.id)
      end

    end

  end
end
```

*Car Model Spec*  **Fails**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Car, type: :model do

  context 'car parts' do

    before :each do
      @p4 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'BPart2')
      @p3 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'APart2')

      @p6 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'BPart3')
      @p5 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'APart3')

      @p2 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'BPart1')
      @p1 = FactoryGirl.create(:part, :name => 'APart1')

    end

    it 'returns parts in alphabetical order' do
      car = FactoryGirl.create(:car, make: 'Nissan', model: 'Murano', parts: [@p4, @p3, @p6, @p5, @p2, @p1])

      expect(car).to be_valid
      expect(car.errors.messages.size).to eq(0)
      expect(car.parts.size).to eq(6)

      car.parts.each do |part|
        puts part.id
      end

      expect(car.parts[0]['name']).to eq('APart1')
      expect(car.parts[1]['name']).to eq('APart2')
      expect(car.parts[2]['name']).to eq('APart3')
      expect(car.parts[3]['name']).to eq('BPart1')
      expect(car.parts[4]['name']).to eq('BPart2')
      expect(car.parts[5]['name']).to eq('BPart3')
    end

  end

end
```

**Summary**
Please help me understand why when accessing them through the model they are not ordered, but when the controller looks them up and renders them, they are.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The only way I have managed to get this to work is to create a 'ordered_parts' method that does the ordering and remove the order from the has_many.  I had to change all my controllers to call 'ordered_parts' instead of the 'parts' method.  Surely there is a better way.  If anyone knows, please help.

```
  def ordered_parts
    self.parts.order('name asc')
  end
```

Comment: I should add that the loop that prints the part ids in the car model spec prints the parts in id order.  So it ends up printing '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'.  It's just not hitting the sort at all.

Comment: I changed it to be: 
  has_many :cars_parts, -> { order('name asc') }
and it hasn't changed the behavior.